# Return nth value in pandas column with str.find() string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column and I need to return the nth character. I used string.find() to get the indexes but I cannot find an answer how to return the values in a pd dataframe column.

| Values | str.find() index | Outcome should be |
| --- | --- | --- |
| asdfa 5-23 | 7 | - |
| kj 1-13 adlkadg | 5 | - |
| ..... | ..... | ... |

Column "Values" is scraped from the internet.

My code to find the second column is :

```
df["str.find() index"] = df["Values"].str.find("-")
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: @Joby Hi. I updated my question with some code.

Answer (score 1):

> Return nth value in pandas column with **str.find()** string

There are many ways to do this, but since you are asking for the method which uses `str.find()`, here are some ways you can do this.

You can do it without explicitly using the `str.find() index` column you created by using `apply`

```
df['Outcome1'] = df['Values'].apply(lambda x: x[x.find("-")])
```

---

But, if you want to use the column you have created with index, then you can use `df.apply` with `lambda` over each row -

```
df['Outcome2'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Values'][row['str.find() index']], axis=1)
```

```
            Values  str.find() index Outcome1 Outcome2
0       asdfa 5-23                 7        -        -
1  kj 1-13 adlkadg                 4        -        -
```